# How to dynamically load views and toggle between them without losing url and url history in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a nav bar with two buttons. Each button renders a view. I am using Jquery to dynamically load those views in one View which then gets rendered on the layout page. That means I am rendering all my views dynamically in one index page.

However, I end up losing the url history and it's not possible to link to those pages because they all get rendered using the one index action and controller that they're being rendered on.

I have tried setting the url from jquery using history.replacestate which works fine, however one issue remains: I do not know how to use the url:s to render a specific view on refresh or when linking to a specific view using the urls I created in replacestate. Is my approcach to dynamic loading wrong or is there a solution that can work with this current implementation?

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/{controller}")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View();
    }
```

> The page argument passes in a URL that I create. Each view needs it's own URL.

```
   function urlHistory(page) {
    history.replaceState(currentState, '', page);
    document.title = `${page}`;
    }
```

> I append each page to the main view and on clicking the nav bar the user can toogle between views.

```
 function appendPage(href, page) {
  $.get(href, {page: page}, function (data) {
    $("#render-tables").html(data);
    }).fail(function () {
    $("#render-tables").empty();
   });
   urlHistory(page);
  }
```

> Rendering both views on the first index action(index.cshtml) that get's hit when logging in i.e the home page razor view.

```
<div id="render-tables"></div>
```

> Which then in turn gets rendered using RenderBody on the Layout view.

Comment: Are you going for a single-page-app here?  Did you need back button/bookmark functionality?  One approach is to use location.append(index#toggle-view=value) and put an event handler on onhashchange, and fire a change on first load of script.  If you don't want to use an existing SPA framework or create your own, you might also just use localstorage and then hide/show specific things based on the value.

Comment: btw, if you are going full SPA here, I would not use the standard _layout.  The @render tags can cause some odd quirks/double-posts.  Create your own static _HEADER and _FOOTER.

Comment: location.append? what does that do exactly? Can you explain this further 
 -> index#toggle-view=value? No, just want the user to be able to refresh the page, back and forward buttons and url links to work so I can link to the two views.

Comment: You can do that with standard page loads... or you'd use something like a hashchange event.  So a standard GET query var would be like: index.htm?view=simple...  if you instead use an ajax call and update the dom yourself, you don't want the page to load, so you use: index.htm#view=simple.   location.append will change the location bar to that href...(and add to history) the browser won't load anything because it thinks you've just clicked a bookmark on the page.  Hashchange will fire which can trigger your javascript.  You can also re-write existing links by handling click events.

Comment: Unless you are going full single-page-application here, seems like you'd just want to use a standard page load.  (No javascript)  Just use "asp-route-viewmode=yourviewmode" in your link.  Then have a "viewmode" property in your controller.

Comment: I have never worked with viewmode before, is this part of asp.net core?  I looked it up and seems to be very little information out there. I also don't really understand what you mean by going full SPA? I am just trying to avoid refresh with dynamic loading and keeping url history and useful url:s that link to each dynamically loaded view. Cheers.

Comment: viewmode is just an example of a query var you can use/bind to in your view and controller.

Comment: You might consider just using localstorage... it would be like a cookie stored on the client-side.  You check the value onload...  shorthand in jQuery for that is $(function() {
   ... check your stored value for view mode here... and fire your view function...
});   Store your view value when you set it...  use localStorage.setItem(key,value);... and localStorage.getItem(key,value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement,I think you could store your current page in cookie or session,
I tried with partial view as below :

```
public IActionResult Partial(string page)
        {            
            var formerpage=HttpContext.Session.GetString("PartialPage");
            string pagename;
            if (page == null&& formerpage==null)
            {
                pagename = "Partial1";                
            }
            else
            {
                pagename = page== null ?formerpage : page;
            }
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("PartialPage", pagename);
            return PartialView(pagename);
        }

        public IActionResult AnotherPartial(string anotherpage)
        {
            var formerpage = HttpContext.Session.GetString("AnotherPartialPage");
            string pagename;
            if (anotherpage == null && formerpage == null)
            {
                pagename = "AnotherPartial1";
            }
            else
            {
                pagename = anotherpage == null ? formerpage : anotherpage;
            }
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("AnotherPartialPage", pagename);
            return PartialView(pagename);
        }
```

Index page:

```
<button id="subBtn1" type="submit">NavBarPartial</button>
<button id="subBtn2" type="submit">Partial</button>
<br />
<button id="subBtn3" type="submit">NavBarAnotherPartial</button>
<button id="subBtn4" type="submit">AnotherPartial</button>

<div id="CrTab">
    
</div>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#subBtn1").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Partial",
            type: "get",
            success: function (datas) {
                console.log(datas);
                $("#CrTab").html(datas);
            }
        })
    });

    $("#subBtn2").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Partial?page=Partial2",
            type: "get",
            success: function (datas) {
                console.log(datas);
                $("#CrTab").html(datas);
            }
        })
    });
    $("#subBtn3").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/AnotherPartial",
            type: "get",
            success: function (datas) {
                console.log(datas);
                $("#CrTab").html(datas);
            }
        })
    });
    $("#subBtn4").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/AnotherPartial?anotherpage=AnotherPartial2",
            type: "get",
            success: function (datas) {
                console.log(datas);
                $("#CrTab").html(datas);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

in View Partial1:

```
<a>Partial1</a>
```

....

The result:

[image]

Comment: So, where does the page argument come from in the controller? Also will this work if I have to different controllers with two index pages. Those pages need to be rendered dynamically i.e click on page1 -> loads index view from controller 1. Click on page2 loads index view from controller 2.  The two views need to be rendered on another controller that gets called first thing i.e gets hit on viewstart and is rendered on the layout using render body.

Comment: the arguement come from query and once it get into  the controller,the arguement would be store in session,and next time you click the button in Navbar,it will load the page with the arguement stored in session instead of the default page, the codes refresh the partialview with ajax